# Gostaria de inserir um alert em javascript em meu botão de ação

Tags: php, javascript, html5, alertdialog

primeiro o chamado de ação para excluir

```
<?php
$aux = 0;
while($resultado = mysql_fetch_object($query))
{
$url_alterar = "form_alterar.php?cod=".$resultado->id;
$url_excluir = "excluir_cad.php?cod=".$resultado->id;
if ($aux % 2 == 0)
```

agora o botão de ação

```
<?="<td><a href=".$url_excluir."><img src='delete.jpg' height='35' width='35'></a></td>";?>
```

e peguei esse código aqui na internet

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
decisao = confirm("Clique em um botão!");
if (decisao){
alert ("Você Apagou o Registro,\n"+decisao);
} else {
alert ("Voce CANCELOU,\n"+decisao);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

já tentei de todas maneiras sem sucesso, acredito que a forma como ele envia a variável para o sistema não permitira que use esse recurso jscript.
Eu já tentei usar direto na ação do botão mas não surtiu resultado, nem na página que é chamada ou no código explicado acima.
Estou pedindo auxilio pois dia 27/09 apresento meu trabalho na faculdade e gostaria de 'enfeitar' já que tudo funciona perfeitamente.
Grato quem puder me ajudar!
abraços

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemplo inline:

```
<a href="delete.php" onclick="return confirm('Prosseguir com a ação?');">excluir</a>
```

Para ser mais claro, para o seu caso:

```
<?="<td><a href=".$url_excluir." onclick="return confirm('Prosseguir com a ação?');><img src='delete.jpg' height='35' width='35'></a></td>";?>
```

Então o trecho `<script>...</script>` pode apagar.

Apenas vou sugerir que mude um pouco

```
<td><a href="<?php echo $url_excluir;?>" onclick="return confirm('Prosseguir com a ação?');><img src='delete.jpg' height='35' width='35'></a></td>
```

Assim, o PHP trabalha menos. Da forma anterior está fazendo o PHP parsear dados desnecessários.

Comment: deu certo assim -> onclick=\"return confirm('Prosseguir com a ação? Você optou por Deletar este Registro')\">

Comment: Porque você colocou o `<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>`?

Comment: onde? tem certeza que sua pergunta foi orientada para mim?

Comment: para evitar que a observação adicional distraísse a atenção.